# Referencing a named array as search criteria to find matching PDF files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

VBA always feels like I'm Icarus in the labyrinth. Level 3 player in a level 100 maze... I'll start to understand one aspect of a problem I'm trying to solve, only to have the solution/resources I've found include another aspect of VBA crucial to the code functioning that I've never heard of.

My overall goal is to use a list of PO#s from a named array as partial name search criteria to find and copy all matching files from the PO# folder to a separate folder.

So far, I've tried to modify someone else's code for a similar but slightly different situation, and given up on that when I couldn't get the list of PO#s to become the search criteria...

I gave up on copying and pasting files for now as I'm a self taught VBA beginner likely lacking a large part of the foundational knowledge of how FSO works, but I planned to use the copied file names and file paths as a way of sorting/copypasting.
So I wrote a code that copies and pastes all of the file names and paths from the source folder into excel, figuring it would be easier to sort them there.

Unfortunately there's 10,8XX files in the folder and it grows every day with the new files being more commonly used, so pulling every file name and path each time I repeat this process (multiple times weekly) is a bit too time consuming.

I'm hoping someone can help me add a filter/match/search function to only return the file names/paths that match my list of PO#s.

I've attempted to use "like" and then use the named list as the criteria for like but I can't seem to figure out how to properly reference a workbook saved on onedrive to reference the named range. I'm not even sure "like" can be used with a range tbh.
"C:\Users\Anthony\OneDrive - CompanyName\Automated parts label template.xlsm"

Updated code:

```
Sub Full_file_path_copy_paste()

Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim objfolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim objfile As Scripting.file
Dim nextrow As Long

Dim POlist As Range
Dim POnum As Variant 'I get a type mismatch error when setting POnum, not sure what type I should put here to get the values from the range in a format that can be used for matching...

'set the list of PO numbers as the range containing the search terms'
Set POlist = Range("POtomatch")
Set POnum = POlist.Value

Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objfolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Anthony\SynologyDrive\@PO")

nextrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row + 1
If objfile Like POnum Then
    For Each objfile In objfolder.Files
        Cells(nextrow, 6) = objfile.Name
        Cells(nextrow, 7) = objfile.Path
        nextrow = nextrow + 1
Next
```

Current code:

```
Sub Full_file_path_copy_paste()

Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim objfolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim objfile As Scripting.file
Dim nextrow As Long

'here is where I've been attempting to include a search/match/filter function'

'return value will be the values on the list of search terms from the named array on an input table'
Dim ReturnValue As Object
'Named array containing the search criteria list'
Set ReturnValue = Workbooks("POtomatch")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objfolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Anthony\SynologyDrive\@PO")

nextrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row + 1
If objfile Like ReturnValue Then
For Each objfile In objfolder.Files
    Cells(nextrow, 6) = objfile.Name
    Cells(nextrow, 7) = objfile.Path
    nextrow = nextrow + 1
Next
End If

End Sub
```

As always, thank you in advance for your patience and help!

Comment: If your list of PO;s is in `Workbooks("POtomatch")`, what is the sheet name and range ?

Comment: "POtomatch" is on the source workbook in the "INPUT" table on the "INPUT" sheet.

In the prior code I refer to it as "POlist"

Comment: Try `If objfile Like "*" & POnum & "*" Then`

Comment: @Loveb This is the syntax I was looking for to get the partial match, but I can't seem to get it to recognize "POnum" as search criteria. 
With POnum dimmed as an object, I keep getting the 424 error when setting the POnum as POlist.value. 
POlist is dimmed as a range and set = the named range, so maybe my syntax is off?
With POnum dimmed as a variant, I get the type mismatch error 13 message.

Comment: @KJ it sounds like you know a muuuuuch simpler way to achieve what I'm going for, which would be amazing! 
Unfortunately, me being new to VBA, I've got absolutely no clue what a fast native command line look up is... 
The list of numbers is in sheet "INPUT" on "INPUTable" with the heading "Customer PO#" and also as a named range "POtomatch".

I'm gonna spend some time on the wikipedia page you linked and googling, hopefully I can parse it out, but if you're feeling generous I wouldn't mindmore shoving in the right direction, haha!

Thanks to both of you!

Comment: `POlist.Value` is an array not an object so don't need `Set`, Just `Dim POnum As Variant: POnum = POlist.Value` or simply `POnum = Range("POtomatch").Value`

Comment: @KJ YES! Exactly my struggle during my short time learning VBA so far. I don't have the vocabulary or background knowledge, so I end up taking the long route. Self taught VBA & excel are the depth of my knowledge now, so I would've never considered running a windows batch task. Do you have any suggestions on learning resources? Most of the excel/VBA learning material I've found isn't comprehensive. It covers one vague way to use a function, but uses unfamiliar/higher level coding to support it, making it impossible to apply in different situations without more learning. It's frustrating...

Comment: @KJ the only thing I know about the CMD window was using it in windows 3.1 to boot in DOS mode for the F1 game I used to play, lol. Thanks for the info, definitely gives me a good starting point to a simpler path!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `LIKE` with an array of values. Join them together with a `|` separator to create a pattern for a regular expression.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Full_file_path_copy_paste()

    Const POFOLDER = "C:\Users\Anthony\SynologyDrive\@PO"

    Dim objFSO As Object, objfolder As Object
    Dim objfile As Object, outputrow As Long
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim sPo As String, sPattern As String, sep As String
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    'join the list of PO numbers with "|"
    For Each cel In Range("POtomatch")
       sPo = Trim(cel.Value2)
       If Len(sPo) > 0 Then ' avoid blanks
           sPattern = sPattern & sep & sPo
           sep = "|"
       End If
    Next
    'Debug.Print sPattern
    
     ' regular expression to pattern match po
    Dim Regex As Object
    Set Regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With Regex
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .pattern = sPattern
    End With
   
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objfolder = objFSO.GetFolder(POFOLDER)
    
    ' scan  files in folder
    With ActiveSheet
        outputrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each objfile In objfolder.Files
             If Regex.test(objfile.Name) Then
                 outputrow = outputrow + 1
                .Cells(outputrow, "F") = objfile.Name
                .Cells(outputrow, "G") = objfile.Path
                i = i + 1
             End If
             n = n + 1
        Next
    End With
    
    MsgBox n & " files scanned, " & vbLf & _
           i & " matched", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The values entered in the POtomatch list do exist in the folder, but this unfortunately returned zero matches when I first ran it.

I ended up resetting the defined area of the POtomatch range. Previously I used the table name and column header, so I changed it to the entire column on that sheet and it found all correct matches!!

If possible, could you explain the process? I can't comprehend the "scan files in folder" part, but I'd love to learn more. Is it scanning the active sheet? How does it know which sheet to output to? What purpose does the regex function serve in this situation?

Comment: @AnthonyDavisSF The scan files is the line `For Each objfile In objfolder.Files`. The `With ActiveSheet` refers to the dot in  `.Cells()` so that is where the results are written to. The regex is a pattern matching engine/object which checks a string against the pattern of po numbers `po1|po2|po3|etc` where `|` is equivalent of `OR`. So `regex.test(name)` is doing check `(name LIKE *po1*) OR (name LIKE *po2*) OR (name LIKE *po3*) etc` in one line.

Comment: I ran out of characters in the last comment. Thank you!!
edit: Even more thanks for the explanation, very helpful!

Comment: @AnthonyDavisSF [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) for more examples of using regular expressions.